# Implementing RBAC functionality in UNIX

Tags: linux, security, unix, access-control, rbac

Hey please help me with this problem. I am new to UNIX systems and i want to ask is Role-Based access control possible in UNIX systems. Please see the details below:

Your manager wants to implement RBAC functionality. Your shop uses a UNIX system. You do not have a system with an implementation of RBAC available to you. You have the basic capabilities of UNIX/LINUX at your disposal for access control. You also have access control list functionality and sudo available. Discuss how far you can go implementing RBAC functionality with the tools at your disposal? What RBAC functionality would be difficult or not practical to implement?

Comment: Yes, if the OS doesn't provide it natively, you can kludge elements of it using sudo and ACLs. If you want a more detailed answer then ask your lecturer.

Comment: RBAC ( role-based-access-control ) is a very wide term. There was patches to linux kernel once, like GRsec or LIDS or similar (OWL? OWA? sth like that), implementing extreme security features, some of them survived more less as "capabilities" ( http://linux.die.net/man/7/capabilities ) One may also configure "RBAC" with openldap and nss-ldap and customized roles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at Power Broker from BeyondTrust - that is if you can buy a solution (I don't work for them).

Also there has been quite some research on this topic at the university of Leuven. Here is their paper: www.cosic.esat.kuleuven.be/sesame/papers/wetice97.pdf

They would know how best to achieve RBAC in UNIX systems.